# Problem to show that $L(\text{span}(u,w))= \text{span}(u,w)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 2 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> -1 & 0 & 0 
> \end{pmatrix}.$ $A$ has an complex eigenvalue $\lambda$. Let $v\in \mathbb{C}^{3\times1}$  be the vector that spans the eigenspace $E(\lambda, A) \subset \mathbb{C}^{3\times1}$ such that $v=u+iw$. Show that $L(\text{span}(u,w))= \text{span}(u,w)$, where $L$ is the linear transformation of the matrix $A$.

It's hard to understand the problem here. I want to show that $L(\text{span}(u,w)) \subset  \text{span}(u,w)$ and $\text{span}(u,w) \subset L(\text{span}(u,w))$. For the first part  i know that $L(x) =Ax =\lambda x$, but i don't know how to show that this is a subset of $\text{span}(u,w)$. What can i do now?

Comment: This problem is rather confusing. Maybe some data is missing, maybe it is just a poorly written problem. First, they talk about the space $\;\Bbb C^3_{\Bbb C}\;$ , of dimension three. Then they decompose a vector $\;v\in\Bbb C^3\;$ in real and imaginary parts, so $\;v=u+iw\;,\;\;u,w\in\Bbb R^3\;$ ....then they take a linear map, which apparently belongs to $\;L(\Bbb R^3, \Bbb R^3)\;$, and ask something about it...Hard to understand...

Comment: I also feel confused. The linear map can be represented as $Ax = \lambda x$. If $x$ is a vector from $E(\lambda, A)$ then $Ax = \lambda x = \lambda(u + iw) = \lambda u + (\lambda)iw$ so $L(\text{span}(u,w)) \subset  \text{span}(u,w)$?

Comment: Beats me...and in your comment, is $\;A\;$ a real or a complex matrix? Seems to be a complex one by what you write, yet $\;L\;$ seems to be a real linear map...very poorly worded question, imo.

Comment: $A$ is a $3$ by $3$ real valued matrix